# Application of the estimation lemma: does this complex integral goes to zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Suppose to have the following integral in the complex plane:
$$
\oint_{C} \frac{1}{1-\lambda^2} \ln\left(\dfrac{\lambda + 1}{\lambda - 1}\right) e(1+\epsilon,\lambda) d\lambda \, ,
$$
where $C$ is a circle of radius $R$ centered in $\lambda = 1$ and
$$
e(x,\lambda) := -\frac{x+\lambda}{2} \ln\left(\frac{x+\lambda}{2}\right) - \frac{x-\lambda}{2}\ln\left(\frac{x-\lambda}{2}\right) \, .
$$
Here $\epsilon > 0$ is to be intended as an arbitrarily small quantity introduced to avoid the branch cut of $e(1,\lambda)$, and we are eventually interested in the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. My question is: is it true that this integral is equal to zero in the limit of $R \rightarrow 0$? If yes, how do I see that? To my knowledge, the standard way to approach this kind of problem is to apply the [estimation lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma) but up to now I cannot come up with an upper bound which goes to zero as $R \rightarrow 0$. Any idea?

Comment: To clarify, letting $I$ be the integral, you are trying to find $\lim_{R \to 0} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} I$?

Comment: I would say yes

Comment: Numerically, it looks like it approaches $\infty$, not $0$.